# Surprising Ruby scoping with while loop

Tags: ruby, while-loop, scope, local-variables

(1)

```
a = [1, 2]
while b = a.pop do puts b end
```

outputs

```
2
1
```

(2)

```
a = [1, 2]
puts b while b = a.pop
```

results in an error

```
undefined local variable or method `b'
```

(3)

```
b = nil
a = [1, 2]
puts b while b = a.pop
```

outputs

```
2
1
```

What is going on? Why is the scope of `b` different in #2 than any of the rest?

```
$ ruby --version
ruby 1.9.3p484 (2013-11-22 revision 43786) [x86_64-linux]
```

---

EDIT: Originally I listed irb's behavior as different. It isn't; I was working in a "dirty" session.

Comment: at least try ruby that's less ancient :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev, fair point. I use the latest in the Ubuntu 14.04 LTS repos :)

Comment: When you read your example #2 line by line from left to the right, is `b` defined at the end of the `puts` statement? I am not surprised, are you? Another even shorter example that fails for the same reason: `p a if a`

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I get the same results in 1.9.3p484, 2.2.3, and 2.4.0 (dev).

Comment: @spickermann, the `if` condition executes first, then the body, i.e. `if condition then action end` is the same as `action if condition` (I thought). But I suppose in the second form Ruby "binds" the variables in a different order or something. Not really sure; docs are pretty unclear on this sutff which is why I am trying to figure it out.

Comment: @PaulDraper: what matters is where the assignment to `b` is located _lexically_ with regard to usages of `b`. In the second example the assignment is after first usage. In all other examples it is located before usages.

Answer (score 0):

The puts statement is executed before the variable 'b' is initially defined, thus resulting in an error.

As a similar example but with an until-statement, consider the following code:

```
a = [1, 2]
begin
  puts "in the block"
end until b = a.pop
```

Would you expect b to be defined within the block?

Technically the only difference is that until stops on a true return value, while while will continue as long as a.pop returns a true value.

The point in both cases is that b is not *in scope* until the assignment *happened*. Right after the assignment, e.g. when the loop returns, b comes available in the current scope. That is called lexical scoping and is how ruby works for local variables like this one.

I found [this article](https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-scope-in-ruby/) to be helpful for understanding scope in ruby.

**Update 1:** In the previous version of my answer I wrote that this is not comparable to an *if*. While this is still true, it has nothing to do with the question, which is a simple scope issue.

**Update 2:** Added a link to some more details explanations regarding scoping in ruby.

**Update 3:** Removed the first sentence, as it was wrong.

Comment: Ha, you are right. I tricked myself when I (ironically) intended to prove the very same statement that it happens with if. Answer updated.

Comment: "The second form is supposed to run the code block at least once before checking the condition. " - This is false. Check for yourself: `a = []; puts "x" while a.pop` displays nothing; `a = []; begin puts "x" end while a.pop` displays an "x". These are two different constructs with different semantics. Aside from the first paragraph, the rest of the answer is good.

Answer (score 0):

Variables are declared to their scope by the lexical parser, which is linear. In `while b = a.pop do puts b end`, the assignment (`b = a.pop`) is seen by the parser before the use (`puts b`). In the second example, `puts b while b = a.pop`, the use is seen when the definition is still unknown, which produces the error.

Answer (score -1):

```
a = [1, 2]
while b = a.pop do puts b end
```

is same as

```
a = [1, 2]
b = a.pop 
puts b
b = a.pop
puts b
```

(2)

```
a = [1, 2]
puts b while b = a.pop
```

is same as this

```
a = [1, 2]
puts b
b = a.pop
puts b
b = a.pop
puts b
```

When b is passed into puts the first time it has not yet been initialized. hence the error message

(3)
b is initialized to nil. even nil is an object in ruby

```
b = nil
a = [1, 2]
puts b while b = a.pop
```

Comment: This is not true; `statement while condition` executes `statement` the same number of times as `while condition; statement; end`. (2) does not run `puts` more times than (1).